# Movement not working on Macbook

Tags: transforms, mouse

When I try to zoom in/out or move the view, nothing happens. All I can do is spin in one stationary spot. I've tried using a mouse, I've tried restarting my computer, and updating Blender to the newest version. I don't even know why it happened in the first place. It was working fine all day then it just wouldn't let me move all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try preferences?

Preferences>navigation>Zoom method>Continue

Enable "Zoom to Mouse Position"

Comment: Just tried it but nothing changed. Thank you for your suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

aaaand it's working again. I'm sure it's some kind of bug, I don't know that I did anything to make it work again but I'm glad it is.